# Unexpected output using print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6.8. on Ubuntu linux 18.04

I have started a tutorial with simple print statements. The code asks a question requiring input, then outputs the answer.

I have duplicated the last line in the code,as it illustrates the problem

```
#!/bin/python3

born = input('What year were you born?')
born = int(born)
age = 2025 - born
print(age)
print('In the year 2025 you will be', age, 'years old')
print 'In the year 2025 you will be', age, 'years old'
```

I expect the result from the first print statement to be;
In the year 2025 you will be 75 years old

and the second should give a syntax error (as it is Python 3 and there are no brackets)

What I get is this;

('In the year 2025 you will be', 75, 'years old')
In the year 2025 you will be 75 years old

Where is this going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have used `python3` to ran this script?. Bcoz only `python2` will print first as in tuple and second as string.

Comment: I tested it on my local Python 3.6.8 setup and it gives a syntax error before even taking inputs. Can you verify if your python3 points to python 2.7.* by any chance?

Comment: Hey @Alex , it seems that your program is working just fine, I tried it and it gave the expected result and also syntax error as no brackets were there in the last print statement

Comment: You expect `python3` should give an error when there is no parenthesis, that's correct. But `python2` can handle both print statements with or without parenthesis. So you are probably running the script using `python2`. Can you provide info how you run the script and what's the output of `which python`?

Comment: How do you run that file?

If you run it with `./filename.py` or `python3 filename.py`, it should work fine.

But the output shows that you may have run the file using `python filename.py` and `python` is a symbolic link to `python2` on many machines.

Comment: Voting to close: the code is fine, it's just being run with the wrong interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at all your suggestions has found the answer. I was not aware that both python2 and python3 both existed on the machine. Running python2 explicitly results in no errors. Running python3 explicitly results in the expected syntax error.

```
alex@Desktop:~/Python$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.8
alex@Desktop:~/Python$ python -V
Python 2.7.15+
alex@Desktop:~/Python$ python test.py
What year were you born?1972
53
('In the year 2025 you will be', 53, 'years old')
In the year 2025 you will be 53 years old
alex@Desktop:~/Python$ python3 test.py
  File "test.py", line 12
    print 'In the year 2025 you will be', age, 'years old'
                                       ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('In the year 2025 you will be', age, 'years old')?
```

Thanks to all respondents for their help

Answer (score 1):

Run `python` or `python3 --version` and see what you got installed, your script would run with any version.
Print with parenthesis works on **3+** while without would work on **2**.